# Angular 2 custom formGroup component

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, components, angular2-formbuilder

i've been searching for this and couldn't find any answers specific for my need:

I have a really big form, which i want to slice in components. My form looks like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
    <div ngModelGroup="someInfo">
        <input type="text" ngModel>
        <input type="text" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div ngModelGroup="someOtherInfo">
        <input type="text" ngModel>
        <select ngModel>SomeOptions</select>
    </div>
</form
```

I want to create separate components for these groups so when i check `form.value` it sees the groups, something like this:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)">
        <some-info-component ngModelGroup="someInfo"></some-info-component>
        <some-other-info-component ngModelGroup="someOtherInfo"></some-other-info-component>
    </form>
```

so how do i make this work, when i try to access form.value.someInfo it is empty object, i've tried with ControlValueAccessor but it only works when i give these components `[ngModel]` but not with ngModelGroup

Comment: Hi, what is question?

Comment: sorry i've updated

Comment: I really suggest you'd use model driven forms for this. Nested formgroups (with child component) are horrible to do with template driven forms :)

Comment: @Alex Reg. form vs template driven, with templates same form group structure can be created as with form driven way. see: https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

Comment: @baHI I know that now, didn't back then. My comment is pretty old :D But thanks anyway, surely that link that you posted is useful for others, so good!